# How do I store a value to use it later in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm just starting with SQL and I wanted to know how to assign the result of a long statement to a short name, just to use it later, as shown in this example. [Is it only possible with the use of variables?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmE0L.png)

Comment: Possibly cursors. Or views. Temp tables might be what you're looking for too. More commonly used are tables expressions (CTEs) / derived tables / etc. Not exactly like a variable though.

Comment: Use INSERT to insert new rows into your tables. Use UPDATE to update existing rows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` to derive your length and make it available to use in both your `select` and `where` clauses.

Untested but this should work:

```
select au_id, au_lname, au_fname, name_length
from authors
cross apply (values(Len(concat(au_lname, ' ', au_fname))))v(name_length)
where name_length > 16
```